# Line in file that has the most characters?

Tags: python, file, input, line

I have a file that has an unknown number of lines with unknown length. How would you write a program that tells which line has the most characters, or in other words, which line is the longest?

I was thinking to make a `for line in myFile` function that uses `len(line)` and appends the length to a new list, so the length of the first line would go index 0, length of second line would go to index 1 etc... Then when there are no more lines to check use the `myList.max()` function to tell me the index of the longest line.

My question is this, is there a better/more efficient way to generate such output? Maybe there's even a built in function that I don't know about that is capable of doing so. You help would be much appreciated.

Comment: i think it will be very easy for others to read the code , rather reading your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
def tuple_compare(tup):
    """
    Input: 2-tuple of the form (anything, line)
    Output: Length of line with trailing newline stripped.
    """
    unused_anything, line = tup
    return len(line.rstrip('\n'))

with open('filename') as fin:
    biggest_line_number, biggest_line = max(enumerate(fin),
                                            key=tuple_compare)
```

Lets unpack this a little. `tuple_compare` just takes the tuples that come out of the `enumerate` function and returns the length of the line that it contains (minus any newline which might be hiding on the end there).  `enumerate` yields a bunch of 2-tuples `(lineno, line)` which is why we take the second element in `tuple_compare` to be the line.  `max` does all the rest of the heavy lifting for us and returns the biggest tuple based on the `key` comparison function.

At the end of the day, we just unpack the tuple into its 2 parts -- the line number and the line text.

Comment: You might not want to include the new line character in the length.

Comment: @thefourtheye -- Yeah, I suppose that could throw off the calculation for the last line only.  Initially I was thinking that every line would have a newline at the end so the systematic offset wouldn't matter.

Comment: @mgilson: thought the same. its a comparison right ? so if every line has it... but maybe not the last one...

Comment: @thefourtheye -- But, the last line could mess with things, so it's best to handle that case.  There are other ways (possibly even more efficient in the general case), but this is the cleanest.

Comment: @FMc -- I thought doing it this way would make it more clear, but then there's the `lambda` barrier to entry ... I suppose I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `key` parameter for `max()` function and treat the file object as an iterator over lines:

```
longest_line = max(myFile, key=len)
```

It assumes that the last line has a newline. Otherwise:

```
longest_line = max((line.rstrip("\n") for line in myFile), key=len)
```

If you want also a line number; you could use `enumerate()`:

```
number, longest_line = max(enumerate(myFile, 1), key=lambda (i, line): len(line))
```

Comment: I was a little unclear whether OP wanted the line number or just the line text...

Comment: Cool.  Nice hat by the way.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('filename') as fin:
    max_len, line_num = (max((len(s),i) for i, s in enumerate(fin))
```

you may want to use `len(s.rstrip('\r'))` as in mgilson's answer

If you need the text from the line:

```
with open('filename') as fin:
    max_len, line_num, line = (max((len(s),i, s) for i, s in enumerate(fin))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another stylistic variant on the basic answer given by several others. I often like this style because it:

- Leverages the idea of a **data pipeline**: each step receives an input stream and generates an output stream. This idiom crops up all over the place: functional programming; Unix shells; map-reduce; etc.
- Often leads to **readable code**: we can apply a meaningful name to each step in the pipeline, and the resulting codes tends have a flat, almost declarative feeling.
- Illustrates **data-centric programming**: if we transform and organize our data in the right way, the algorithmic aspect of our computation shrinks to trivial proportions, even to the point of practically disappearing -- in this case, we just call `max()` on the last stage of the pipeline.

For many other (and much more interesting) examples in this vein, search for David Beazley's online writings on iterators, generators, and coroutines.

```
with open('path/to/file') as fh:

    # Each pipeline step is a generator.
    stripped = (ln.rstrip('\n') for ln in fh)
    lengths  = ((len(ln), i, ln) for i, ln in enumerate(stripped))

    # The data directly answers our question.
    # We get max length, line number, and the line.
    print max(lengths)
```